# How to create a String type array without declaring the range in java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, exception

In java I have created a String type array by this line `String [] ars = {};` No error is showing at this line. But when I am trying to insert a string by this line `ars[i++] = g;` where i is equals to 0, it gives me `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0`
why?

Comment: Size of Arrays are fixed. You should chose a [Java Collection](http://www.eozkan.com/2013/06/java-collections.html) class which fit your needs. I think ArrayList may be one of the Collection for your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays are fixed-size, and you cannot add elements to them after creation. Since your array has a size of 0, accessing it at index 0 is out of bounds.

If you want to add elements to your collection of `String`s after the creation of your collection, then you might want to think about using a collection such as `java.util.ArrayList<String>`. You can use it like this:

```
//import java.util.*;
ArrayList<String> ars = new ArrayList<String>();
ars.add(g);
```

Comment: what type of data will be returned by `ars.size();`? String or Integer? @Jashaszun

Comment: @TusharTushKhush Seeing as the `size` method returns the size of the `ArrayList`, it returns an `Integer`. Returning a `String` would not make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are fixed in size. Elements cannot be added if the index equals or exceeds the array size. i.e. only values of `0` to `array.length` - 1 can be used. Here you are attempting to assign a value at index `0` to a zero-sized array resulting in the `AIOOBE`.

Use a collection such as `ArrayList` which can expand its capacity if required when elements are added.

Answer (score 1):

In java you are required to specify how big you want your Array and you cannot change that size without creating a new array.

The best way is to use [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) or another implementation of [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

Answer (score 1):

Don't use an array.  Use an ArrayList.  Arrays in Java are fixed length when you allocate them and can never be increased.  Your code makes ars reference an array of length 0, so it can never be bigger unless you point it at a new array.  That's the purpose of the ArrayList class-  to be a variable length array that can grow/shrink with time.

Answer (score 0):

This erro ocuurs cause you have nothing in [0], nothing in {};

this way, you have something: string a = {"zero", first}, where a[0] = zero, and a[1] = first

you can try too, this way;

declare a int tam = 0;

and create you array: String a = new String[tam];

so after you could alternate the length of array, 
changing the variable tam;